# Adding The Number Of People Checked In To A Place With Facebook API v-4

Tags: php, facebook, api, location

As of now i'm using `tagged_places` to get a users recent places. This returns in this format,

```
  [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 10000000000000018
                            [created_time] => 2014-05-30T21:41:11+0000
                            [place] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 164380000000000000
                                    [location] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [city] => New YOrk
                                            [country] => United States
                                            [latitude] => 25.628888888
                                            [longitude] => -44.000000000346
                                            [state] => OK
                                            [street] => 444 S Mart Ave
                                            [zip] => 74224-5022
                                        )

                                    [name] => Bob's Pub 
                                )
```

This is great but...

In facebook I notice when clicking the location icon on a post box when posting the status, generates places around you showing how many people were or have been checked in there.

so it might say `tulsa downtown 26 people were here` as you're creating the post with your location.

Is there a way to get the number of people that were there like its showing in the feed when posting your location?

This appears to not be friends but just a total amount of people.

Thanks!

This is my current code.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


// include required files form Facebook SDK

// added in v4.0.5
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'facebook/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'foo','foo' );

 // login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.placonweb.com/' );


// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }

} else {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data with response           
$graphObject = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,tagged_places' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the question? You want to extract the `26` out of a string or you want a different API call?

Comment: If it says there is 'X' amount of people at that location I want that value. I dont care how I get it. The easiest way possible. I just dont know if its possible or how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `page` api which will return the number of `checkins` for the location.

- Field: checkins
- Description: Number of checkins at a place represented by a Page
- Type: int32

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/